# How to get layout like this in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple responsive HTML table and I am trying to get a layout like on picture below:

[image]

As you can see my problem is with this ***year*** column.  Right now I need to paste empty:

```
 <th scope="row"></th>
```

Also that whole column has border because of this empty HTML tags.

Is it possible to get layout like in this picture, also this is my HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Short</th>
                <th scope="col">Exam</th>
                <th scope="col">P</th>
                <th scope="col">S</th>
                <th scope="col">A</th>
                <th scope="col">SJ</th>
                <th scope="col">TJ</th>
                <th scope="col">PK</th>
                <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
                <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
                </td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
                <td data-title="P">4</td>
                <td data-title="S">4</td>
                <td data-title="A">0</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
                <td data-title="PK">0</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th class="sem" scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">-</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
                <td data-title="P">-</td>
                <td data-title="S">-</td>
                <td data-title="A">-</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
                <td data-title="PK">-</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">-
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td data-title="Short">-</td>
                <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
                <td data-title="P">-</td>
                <td data-title="S">-</td>
                <td data-title="A">-</td>
                <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
                <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
                <td data-title="PK">-</td>
                <td data-title="ECTS">-
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r6jqvk4s/1/

Comment: `row-span` should give you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to count your tr children and then insert the rowspan attribute with the count value found :

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');// look for tbody
var thscoped = document.querySelector('tbody .sem');// look for the th.sem inside tbody
var count = 0;
for (var ch = tbody.firstChild; ch; ch = ch.nextSibling)// will find tr
  if (ch instanceof HTMLElement) count++; // will count them

thscoped.setAttribute("rowspan", count); // insert the rowspan attribute once count is done
```

```css
/* SEE ME */
.sem {border:solid;}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Short</th>
        <th scope="col">Exam</th>
        <th scope="col">P</th>
        <th scope="col">S</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">SJ</th>
        <th scope="col">TJ</th>
        <th scope="col">PK</th>
        <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
        </td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

jsfiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/34198okz/

Answer (score 0):

My advice is : use a framework (it makes things easier). Here is an example using Materialize (https://materializecss.com/table.html).

**Note: in this example all files are in the same folder**

code for ***responsiveTable.html*** is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="materialize.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personalize.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src= "materialize.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>

<table class="highlight">
<thead class="corBackgroundThead">
<tr>
<th scope="col">Year</th>
<th scope="col">Short</th>
<th scope="col">Exam</th>
<th scope="col">P</th>
<th scope="col">S</th>
<th scope="col">A</th>
<th scope="col">SJ</th>
<th scope="col">TJ</th>
<th scope="col">PK</th>
<th scope="col">ECTS</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="sem" scope="row"></th>
<td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
<td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
<td data-title="P">4</td>
<td data-title="S">4</td>
<td data-title="A">0</td>
<td data-title="SJ">0</td>
<td data-title="TJ">0</td>
<td data-title="PK">0</td>
<td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"></th>
<td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
<td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
<td data-title="P">4</td>
<td data-title="S">4</td>
<td data-title="A">0</td>
<td data-title="SJ">0</td>
<td data-title="TJ">0</td>
<td data-title="PK">0</td>
<td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"></th>
<td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
<td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
<td data-title="P">4</td>
<td data-title="S">4</td>
<td data-title="A">0</td>
<td data-title="SJ">0</td>
<td data-title="TJ">0</td>
<td data-title="PK">0</td>
<td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

code for ***personalize.css*** is below:

> thead th {
>       background-color: #607c8a !important
>   }

you can download the ***materialize.min.css*** and ***materialize.min.js*** files  from the link below:
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/releases/download/1.0.0/materialize-v1.0.0.zip

The result you will get:
[responsive (highlight) table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUSlc.jpg)